# List all joints existing in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How to see what joints are existing during a simulation? Just to be sure that my dynamically spawned joints are actually there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9018/list-all-joints-existing-in-gazebo/) by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2015-06-29**:
this is answered here http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7657/what-are-the-various-joint-types-available-in/

**Comment by [mehdi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1195/mehdi/) on 2015-06-29**:
Sorry my question was a little bit misleading, I was asking about the Joints existing during a simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

currently you cannot visualize dynamically created joints:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1077/visualizing-dynamically-created-joints

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0